# Implementing notification to webview

Tags: android

I want to implement notification like whenever something new add to the website it send a notification to the user or trigger certain words. If you can post the code that would be really helpful thanks.

```
 public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);
    String url = "https://www.example.com";
    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView4);
    web.loadUrl(url);

    final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView4);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);

   webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
   return true;   }
 });
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
}}
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.